# Disable mouse hover events for dock when transparent window is placed above it

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, dock, osx-leopard, osx-snow-leopard

I am developing a Desktop application that displays a transparent NSWindow at screen saver window level and covers the entire screen. When I hover the mouse over dock, app names tip panel is displayed even if my transparent window is displayed over dock. What is the reason for this? I have set `setIgnoresmouseMovedEvents:` to NO on my window.

Comment: I need to support this for Leopard also